# Count number of columns in grid

Tags: wpf, gridview

I'm new to WPF and I'm trying to create a grid where a button is fixed to the last column. The number of rows and columns is adjusted by user input.

Eventually the user clicks a button to add more rows/columns and the button is always affixed to the last row/column. My thought is if I can get the number of rows/columns I can always change the button position via binding. I've tried `Count` but that doesn't seem to work...or maybe I'm accessing it wrong.

XAML

```xml
<Button Click="addcolumn" Grid.Column="{Binding Path=Colsize}">+</Button>
```

C#

```
public int colsize = 0;
        public int Colsize
        {
            get { return colsize; }
            set { colsize = value; }
        }
public void addcolumn(Object sender,  RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            maincolumn = new ColumnDefinition();
            maincolumn.Width = new GridLength(50);
            maingrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(maincolumn);
            colsize = maingrid.ColumnDefinitions.Count;
        }
```

The user is able to add columns but the button stays fixed at column 0. I've tried `selectivescrollinggrid` but didn't work then. I'm not sure `datagrid` does what I want but open to suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know
1. Grid.Column is not dependent on the property, only the dependency appears to achieve the binding notification.
2. The properties you bind need to implement the InotifyProperty interface to achieve the purpose you want.